# Low confidence score in SVC for example from training set

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Here is my code for SVC classifier.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)
train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(training_data)
classifier_linear = svm.LinearSVC()
clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(classifier_linear) 
linear_svc_model = clf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
```

`training_data` here is a list of english sentences and `train_lables` are the labels associated. I do the usual stopwords removal and some preprocessing before creating final version of `training_data`. Here is how my testing code:

```
test_lables = ["no"]
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_lables)
prediction_linear = clf.predict_proba(test_vectors)
counter = 0 
class_probability = {}
lables = []
for item in train_labels:
    if item in lables:
        continue
    else:
        lables.append(item)
for val in np.nditer(prediction_linear):
    new_val = val.item(0)
    class_probability[lables[counter]] = new_val
    counter = counter + 1
sorted_class_probability = sorted(class_probability.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(sorted_class_probability)
```

Now when I run the code with a phrase that is already there in the training set (a word 'no' in this case), it identifies properly, but the confidence score is even below `.9`. The output is as follows:

```
[('no', 0.8474342514152964), ('hi', 0.06830103628879058), ('thanks', 0.03070201906552546), ('confused', 0.02647134535600733), ('ok', 0.015857384248465656), ('yes', 0.005961945963546264), ('bye', 0.005272017662368208)]
```

When I am studying online, I have seen that usually confidence score for data already in the training set is closer to `1` or almost `1` and rest of them are really negligible. What can I do to get better confidence score? Should I be worried that if I add more classes to it, the confidence score will further dip and it will be difficult for me to surely point out one standout class?

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please leave a comment saying why. Shoot and scoot helps no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your scores help you classify your inputs correctly, you shouldn't worry at all. If anything, if your confidence on the input already in your training data is too high, that probably means your method has overfit to the data, and cannot generalize to the unseen data.

However, you can tune the *complexity* of your method by changing the penalization parameters. In the case of a `LinearSVC`, you have both the `penalty` and the `C` parameter. Try different values of those two and observe the effect. Make sure you also observe the effect on an unseen test set.

Just a not that the values of `C` should be in exponential space, eg. `[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]` for you to see meaningful effects.

The [`SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) may be relevant to your case if you're interested in such linear models and tuning your parameters.